# Trigger Lambda based on Crawler output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have a setup wherein I need to trigger a lambda function when my glue crawler has run and data is ready in redshift. Is there a way to create such a trigger?

Edit:

I added an Event bridge rule for crawler state change, that works and triggers the lambda function but it triggers when any of my crawlers are running. I want to isolate it to trigger only after a specific crawler is run. I tested with the code below but it doesn't seem to pick my crawler name. Is there any other way to specify the crawler name in the rule or am I making a syntactical error?

```
{
  "source": ["aws.glue"],
  "detail-type": ["Glue Crawler State Change"],
  "eventName": "crawler_name",
  "detail": {
    "state": ["Succeeded"]
  }
```

}

Comment: Example of SNS triggering Lambda function on AWS Glue job state change [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-job-fail-retry-lambda-sns-alerts/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Add an EvenBridge rule with the following Event Pattern

```js
{
  "source": ["aws.glue"],
  "detail-type": ["Glue Crawler State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "crawlerName": ["newton_pfi_new_raw_to_source"],
    "state": ["Succeeded"]
  }
}
```